# Is throwing exceptions in Debug mode a bad idea?

Tags: design, design-patterns, architecture, code-quality, source-code

I am working in an `iOS` project which have two schemes enabled from configurations,

- Release
- Debug

As you know `Debug` scheme is used for developers while developing features and testing etc. However, `Release` scheme is used for generating official final artefact to upload in App Store. Currently my application quality is not good and many exceptions are not properly handled by developers (most of them are ignored). In current codebase most of the methods are  developed in such a way that when exceptions happens they are catched and printed in log. Let's say here is a pseudocode,

```
func doSomething() {
    do {
        //code that might generate exception
    } catch let error {
        print("Error: \(error)")
    }
}
```

However, I feel many exceptions should be thrown in development phase and developers should invest more time to analyse and fix them. For that reason I want to log exceptions only in `Release` mode but not in `Debug` mode. Let’s say my intention is to refactor the above similar code as below,

```
func doSomething() throws  {

    do {
        //code that might generate exception e
    } catch let error {

        #if Release
            print("Error: \(error)")
        #else Debug
            throw error
        #endif
    }
}
```

Is there is any other issues might arise for this approach? Is it a bad idea anyway?

Comment: Why did you take a deleted question of yours and rewrite it as a completely new, unrelated question rather than posting a new question?

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm i am banned from posting new questions from that site. Thats the only option i have left.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm please find the evidence of my struggle here https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8939/208831

Comment: @RobertHarvey in which  sense this post is too broad? This is a specific design pattern problem where I have even tried to put code level example. If these is too broad there are thousands of posts in this site with many up votes which you moderators guys didn't think to hold at all (i.e https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/revisions/164256/1).

Comment: Design pattern are defined for an identified problem. What you present as a design pattern is an just an idea that you might want to propagate to all your codebase whatever the specific piece of code should do as such, it is too broad. This idea might only be good if you have to rely on a unreliable (say for instance legacy) piece of software. Normally your debug code should works exactly the same as production code.

Comment: @Walfrat being more theoretical, software engineering site is by nature supposed to deal with such kind of little abstract stuffs sometimes unlike other sites. However, if a tag seems not suitable that can be removed by anyone. Holding a question without describing whats the problem does not help the poster. How do you agree the linked post i referred in my comment was not too broad then? Anyway, even your comment already hinted some parts of the answer of my posted question. Someone like you just could have written as an answer? We are here to learn not to spoil the site.

Comment: @Walfrat with due respect I suggest you to look into your top answered post. The OP asked ‘When is it appropriate to completely suppress all errors like this?’ with a code-snap. Don’t you really believe the post could be marked as too broad for the same reason my post was marked?

Comment: The top question asked the reason behind a general admitted good practices. Which is effectively on-topic and a good question that is answerable with a factual Answer. Moreover, the general advice is to understand why best practices are there and so why sometimes you might need to deviate from it. And that is also why the current answer in this post is "there is no hard and fast rules how to handles errors". You ask for a practices on your own not a best practices, which may invite more opinions than a factual answer. So I do think this question is a on the borderline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no hard and fast rules how to handle errors. When an operation could (theoretically) produce an error, you need to look at the situation, each situation individually, and decide how to cope with it.

Case 1: Errors that you are convinced cannot happen. Check for them, and in a debug version have an assertion that will stop execution in the debugger, so you can examine why the error (that you were convinced couldn't happen) did happen, and what to do about it, and change your code.

Case 2: Errors that you can fix. Add code to fix them.

Case 3: Errors that the user can fix, possibly by talking to their admin, sometimes by trying again: Find the best advice to the user, and show an alert to the user advising them how to fix. Change your code so it doesn't cause damage in this case.

Case 4: Errors that you have no idea how to handle. You say "if this ever goes wrong, we are just ****ed.". Decide whether you want to handle them like case 1, or you might want to change your code so that shuts down your app safely.